# How can I prevent overflow from a fieldset?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am trying to utilize a fieldset element as a sidebar navigation container for it's look. Maybe it has nothing to do with the fieldset and I'm not the best with CSS's small nitpicky details but I can't figure out how to keep the fieldset strictly in its own column while pushing text and any overflowing elements to the next line. Here's a snippet of the problem code and the link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5vjncf3z/

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-3">
    <fieldset id="sideNav">
        <legend>Page Name</legend>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p>Page descriptionasiauhefaiouehfoaiuehfaiowehfaowieufhwoiefuhaoiweufhawieufha</p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="well">
        <h2>Page content</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your fieldset:

```
#sideNav { word-break: break-all;}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tj833dms/